# 500 Internal Server Error When Deploying Next.js Blog on Firebase Functions

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working on deploying a blog section built with Next.js as part of my ReactJS project, aiming to enhance SEO through Server Side Rendering (SSR). For this purpose, I'm using Firebase Functions. However, I am encountering a persistent issue: a 500 Internal Server Error.

Below is the code snippet for my Firebase function setup:

```
const next = require("next");

// Initialize Next.js app
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "functions/.next" } });

const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

// Create HTTP function for handling requests
exports.nextServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return nextApp.prepare().then(() => handle(request, response));
});
```

The error message suggests a problem related to the system not finding any pages or app directory in the expected location. I am looking for insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Any advice or guidance on what might be going wrong and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

*My code structure:*

[image: my code structure]

**Firebase hosting link:** https://liberameappblog.web.app/blog

*Firebase emulator output:*

[image: firebase emulator output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic response is 500 Internal errors. To determine the precise mistake, you need to examine the logs.

Use npm run dev to try running your Next.js application locally and check if there are any problems. If so, there may be an issue with the deployment setup.

Look for any error messages in the logs located in the Firebase Console. The command to examine logs on your terminal is as follows:

Make sure your project's directory structure is configured properly. The location where Firebase Functions expects to locate the Next.js build output should match the value of the distDir option in your Next.js setup. It appears to be set to "functions/.next" in your instance.

Ensure that all your project dependencies are correctly installed and up to date. Run npm install in your project directory to make sure all required packages are installed.

Comment:  Thank you. I have checked the logs: _The error message suggests a problem related to the system not finding any pages or app directory in the expected location_.

**There is an image of my code structure, any suggestions?**

Comment: There are a few things you may look for if the error message says that the system cannot locate any pages or the app directory at the specified location:
Appropriate Directory Organization, Examine the Firebase Function Path. 

Verify that the firebase.json file is set up appropriately to handle rewrites using the appropriate function. The proper function name ought to be indicated in the rewrites section:

Verify that the pages directory in your Next.js application contains legit pages. ensure you have the necessary files in your pages/blog directory, for instance, if you have a blog.